# suspendCoroutine hangs when resumeWithException is called with mockk mock

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

I have an external API that I want to test against, but in which I cannot construct exceptional types myself. Consider this following small example:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.DelicateCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

class Foo {
    lateinit var cb: Callback

    interface Callback {
        fun good()
        fun bad(e: Throwable)
    }

    fun something(cb: Callback) {
        this.cb = cb
    }
}

class Test {
    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val foo = Foo()
        runBlocking {
            launch {
                delay(300)
                //foo.cb.bad(mockk<IllegalStateException>(relaxed = true))
                foo.cb.bad(IllegalStateException())
            }
            GlobalScope.async {
                suspendCoroutine { cont ->
                    foo.something(object : Foo.Callback {
                        override fun good() {
                            cont.resume(Unit)
                        }

                        override fun bad(e: Throwable) {
                            cont.resumeWithException(e)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }.await()
        }
    }
}
```

If I execute this test as-is, the exception is thrown and the test turns red, just as expected. If I however comment out the call with the `IllegalStateException` constructor and use the mockk mock instead, the test hangs indefinitely and I never return from the `suspendCoroutine` block. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior arises from the fact that you use a relaxed mock of an `Exception` that returns a relaxed mock when `getCause` is called. This leads to an infinite recursion when some mechanism inside of `resumeWithException` tries to get the root cause of your exception.

You can fix this by simply specifying the cause of your mocked exception, e.g.

```
mockk<IllegalStateException>(relaxed = true) {
    every { cause } returns null
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, using a not relaxed mock didn't work in first place either, but your explanation makes total sense. Thank you!